# How can I calculate 10^400, without MATLAB returning "inf"?

Tags: matlab, calculus

I am dealing with very big numbers, on the scale of `10^500`,`10^800`.
When I try to calculate `10^309` it reurns `inf`.

```
>> 10^309
ans =
   Inf
```

I tested `format long` it also returns `inf`.

```
>> format long 
>> 10^309
ans =
   Inf
```

I also tested the `vpa` function:

```
vpa(10^309,309)
ans =
    Inf
```

how can I calculate and use big numbers in my calculation?
I cannot use a logarithm, because I require all digits in the very large numbers. i.e. I want MATLAB to return the following for `10^308`

```
vpa(10^308,308)
    ans =
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Did you consider that the number you want may in fact be too large for any sensible computer to represent?

Comment: can you change the unit of your values, for example, from nano meter to light year?

Comment: IKavanagh  i want to use matlab as possible.

Comment: rayryeng,you are right ,whats the bigest number that i can use for compuer ,do  you know?can i calculation this large number with creation a c++ function

Comment: Regarding your last comment, this question has already been asked and has a very interesting answer and article linked to it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708461/biggest-number-in-computer-ever)

Comment: user3528438,my data is not physics,its related number theory,discreet math,it is digit number chain .this chain  has been used in my operation

Comment: brodroll ,i want to a solution in matlab.is it impossible!thanks

Comment: if that's the case, you want to avoid using floating point numbers, then the best matlab can offer is `uint64`, which has a range between [0, 18446744073709551615]. Symbolic is another option, or some kind of big integer library.

Comment: @stackprogramer I was referring to the question "whats the bigest number that i can use for compuer" you asked to rayryeng

Comment: user3528438,thanks for reply and attention,10^309 is out of range  18446744073709551615,                                                                              brodroll  yes,thanks for your reply and eattention                                               but  i think i can write this calculator with a c++ vectors

Comment: The largest real valued floating point number that MATLAB can represent on your computer can be found by `realmax`.  On my computer, it's currently:  `1.7977e+308`.  This is probably why you are getting `Inf` when trying values that have an exponent beyond 308.

Comment: rayryeng dear you are right,my realmax is 1.797693134862316e+308
          ,,  i have a idea tha i created a special code with vectors in c++,        my mean in a first second i need a number and it's digit and in second 2,i delete the former number and i  test new number and i don't need big memory  and so on...

Comment: If you install the  external (and freeware)  `gmp` library there are tools on FileExchange that will allow you to do unlimited precision work with floats.  But there really is no excuse for working with low precision numbers of the magnitudes you've posted.  Please read up on the difference between precision and magnitude, and figure out how to scale your numbers into something reasonable.

Comment: @ Carl Witthoft  thanks for attention,i soon test gmp,....  answer "Please read up on the difference between precision and magnitude, and figure out how to scale your numbers into something reasonable."                         my data is chain of number that uses in number theory,discreet math , there is not physics data.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use the Variable Precision Arithmetic module `vpa`.  Just make sure you put the exponent **outside** of the `vpa` call:

```
>> A = vpa(10)^400

A =

1.0e400
```

Comment: thanks  rayryeng,ofcourse   i need digits and i cann't use  1.0e400

Comment: In any case, thank you very much, special for introducing realmax

Comment: @stackprogramer my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the [Variable Precision Integer Arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic) library that's on the MATLAB file exchange. An example of its use is as follows:

```
>>> A = vpi(17)^17 
ans = 
827240261886336764177

>>> 17 + A^17 
ans = 
39786732894291535047752038041559739510060813980024082 
30012867731573722066105737100731556603857745946047229 
53759676529121155309750944582301597489457676380805029 
59227566911971103003303064782118652210655457390045806 
99039190393572334521701109889855832341416056005878848 
49943142324389193616484809157960034059531548585473213 
36465170635561696613297503569949729314
```

This seems to be what you want.

Comment: i run   this has error!                                                        >> A = vpi(17)^17 
ans = 
827240261886336764177
Undefined function or variable 'vpi'.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 >>     factorial(vpi(171)) 
Undefined function or variable 'vpi'.

Comment: Is the folder where you downloaded the submission in your matlab's path? An easy fix would be to unzip the downloaded file directly into the folder you  have the script you are running

Comment: @brodroll   it works, i copied it to path and worked  thanks very much            A = vpi(17)^17
A =
    827240261886336764177

Comment: it works nice.A = vpi(10)^309
A =
    10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000

Comment: but  for this it   has errors:        vpi(4222)*45555555555555555555555555555555                                                                                                                                                                Error using vpi (line 160)
If N is a double, it may be no larger than 2^53 - 1

Error in  .*  (line 79)
      INT1 = vpi(INT1);

Error in  *  (line 27)
  INT = INT1.*INT2;

Comment: vpi(10988888877777)*10^20
Error using vpi (line 160)
If N is a double, it may be no larger than 2^53 - 1

Error in  .*  (line 79)
      INT1 = vpi(INT1);

Error in  *  (line 27)
  INT = INT1.*INT2;

Comment: this tool  can't  calculate for number  large than  2^53 - 1       so  i can n't finish my project

Comment: Try casting: `vpi(4222)*int32(45555555555555555555555555555555)`